# Android Array list to find the minimum value from custom data type arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, minimum

I am working on family tracker application. I need to find the latest location of users. For that I am using time difference method. I have created custom data type list in which I have stored time differences and latitude/longitude, but I am unable to find the minimum time difference and that latitude/longitude.

Arraylist contains id, lat, long and time differences.

My Code:

```
timediff = SystemDateTime.getTime() - ServerDateTime.getTime();
TimeDifferenceModel timeDiffModel = new TimeDifferenceModel(Id, timediff, lat, lang); 
DifferenceData.add(timeDiffModel);
```

**TimeDifferenceModel**

```
public TimeDifferenceModel(String id, long timediff, double lat, double lang)
{ 
    this.id = id; 
    this.timediff = timediff; 
    this.lat = lat; 
    this.lang = lang; 
}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: You can implement a comparator to order your arraylist with the items ServerDateTime : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property